# Change the text for the Touch ID pop up

Tags: ios, touch-id

We need to do some changes in the Touch ID pop up.

1. Can we make the App Name bold?
2. Can we remove the “” from the App Name?
3. Is the reason text optional?

Comment: It seems that in `-evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:` for the `localizedReason` param you should be able to put your text. Don't think that you can change the title or remove the "". It seems that the reason can be nil, or maybe try with a a string with length 0 (@"").

Comment: Ok Thanks, i will try nil or @"".

Comment: i tested with empty string but Its a non nullable string. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This popup is shown when you call the evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply: method and has only 3 arguments:

1. policy: The policy to evaluate.
2. localizedReason: The app-provided reason for requesting authentication.
3. reply: Reply block that is executed when policy evaluation finishes.

In short, you can only choose a string message that will be shown to the user.

Comment: Ok Thanks,  What about localizedReason Text?

Comment: I tested with empty string but Its a non nullable string. Thanks.